# How to write batch file to check file integrity

Tags: batch-file

I would like to write batch file to check file integrity before changing. But I don't know how to write it. Please give some advice for me.

Comment: What constitutes file integrity in your eyes?

Comment: Integrity meaning what? If you mean corrupt then I doubt you could do this in any language, never mind batch.

Answer (score 0):

To check the integrity of a file first you need to have a verification file to compare if something has change (SFV file for example) or save the hash in any other type of file, but you need it.

You can use external commands to check any type of hash for the file, and then compare it after, for example you can use the "crc32.exe" commandline app to check the crc hash of a file.

You want to do this with native Batch commands? Isn't possible.

Comment: Your comment is userfull for me.

Comment: Hey Elektro, Is crc32.exe is hashing algorithm right? If yes, I think md5 is better than crc32.

Comment: of course is better, but I only tell you the basic hash because I don't know external commands for DOS to generate and check MD hashes. I use a profesional APP for this: https://sourceforge.net/projects/objectmonitor/  don't forget to accept my answer if helped you.

Comment: Don't be serious. I just wanna to make sure my understanding.